# On average, what kind of precision should I expect when debossing over an existing print in a small run?

Tags: print-design

This question most definitely deserves to be asked directly to my printer but since they're currently on leave for the week, figured I'd give it a shot here to get a general idea on how I should approach my design.

I'm getting a text printed and want to add a debossed detail in the existing printed word spaces. It's a small run of 500 cards at the most. Quick and dirty example:

> Let's/say/all/the/slashes/here/are/debossed/but/the/text/is/printed.

So it's a limited space and could easily look off center. On average, what kind of precision range should I expect? 0.5 point? 2 points? 1/16 inch? More?

Comment: I think this *has* to be asked of the printer. Each print provider will have a different tolerance based on their set up. Guessing... in general I'd say a standard trap amount, 0.25pt or 0.5pt maybe. But some quick printers will push that to 1pt or larger.

Comment: It will be asked. I'm mostly wondering if there's a standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a standard as such Emilie, it is entirely dependant on your printer due to the equipment at use and the hand using it.
Here is a general guide:

Note: All measurements are in inches.

Tolerances to Remember

Minimum embossing width – .040 through .010 substrates. Thicker substrates may require adjusting.

Maximum height of emboss – 2.5 times the material thickness.

Height tolerance – plus/minus .005

Registration – plus/minus .015 (registration to graphic image.)

Minimum distance between embossed areas – .050

Taken from: http://www.ppsinc.com/detailedembossing~20